Most simple lmap, how to return a value
This works OK:
> lmap x {a b c} {string trim cmd.$x}
cmd.a cmd.b cmd.c

> lmap x {a b c} {list cmd.$x}
cmd.a cmd.b cmd.c

In both cases the string trim and list are somewhat useless. And by useless I mean they don't modify/add something to the result. Is there a better way?
I tried these, but they don't have the result I want:
> lmap x {a b c} {return cmd.$x}
cmd.a

> lmap x {a b c} {return -code return cmd.$x}
cmd.a

> lmap x {a b c} {return -code continue cmd.$x}
cmd.a


What happens if you use lmap x {a b c} {cmd.$x}?

Returns an invalid command name "cmd.a"

This exact reason is why string cat was added (cat for concatenate, by analogy with the Unix command cat and the C function strcat()). The operation it does is basic to the Tcl language as you have noticed, but having it as a command makes lmap easier.
lmap x {a b c} {string cat cmd.$x}

That lmap body script compiles to maximally efficient bytecode.
Before string cat was added, the official way was return -level 0 cmd.$a which ends up being the same thing, but really isn't mnemonic! It was found to be totally unwieldy in the 8.6 beta releases, so string cat got swiftly done and there was rejoicing among the beta testers.

To expand on what I mean:
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble lambda {{} {
    lmap x {a b c} {string cat cmd.$x}
}}
ByteCode 0x1ee2cfafbe0, refCt 1, epoch 19, interp 0x1ee2b47a820 (epoch 19)
  Source "lmap x {a b c} {string cat cmd.$x}"
  Cmds 2, src 34, inst 22, litObjs 2, aux 1, stkDepth 6, code/src 0.00
  Proc 0x1ee2cfc5630, refCt 1, args 0, compiled locals 1
      slot 0, scalar, "x"
  Exception ranges 1, depth 1:
      0: level 0, loop, pc 12-17, continue 19, break 20
  Commands 2:
      1: pc 0-20, src 0-33        2: pc 12-17, src 16-32
  Command 1: "lmap x {a b c} {string cat cmd.$x}"
    (0) list 0
    (5) push1 0         # "a b c"
    (7) foreach_start 0
                [jumpOffset=-7, vars=[%v0]]
  Command 2: "string cat cmd.$x..."
    (12) push1 1        # "cmd."
    (14) loadScalar1 %v0        # var "x"
    (16) strcat 2
    (18) lmap_collect
    (19) foreach_step
    (20) foreach_end
    (21) done

% tcl::unsupported::disassemble lambda {{} {
    lmap x {a b c} {expr {"cmd.$x"}}
}}
ByteCode 0x1ee2cfafde0, refCt 1, epoch 19, interp 0x1ee2b47a820 (epoch 19)
  Source "lmap x {a b c} {expr {\"cmd.$x\"..."
  Cmds 2, src 32, inst 23, litObjs 2, aux 1, stkDepth 6, code/src 0.00
  Proc 0x1ee2cfc6430, refCt 1, args 0, compiled locals 1
      slot 0, scalar, "x"
  Exception ranges 1, depth 1:
      0: level 0, loop, pc 12-18, continue 20, break 21
  Commands 2:
      1: pc 0-21, src 0-31        2: pc 12-18, src 16-30
  Command 1: "lmap x {a b c} {expr {\"cmd.$x\"..."
    (0) list 0
    (5) push1 0         # "a b c"
    (7) foreach_start 0
                [jumpOffset=-8, vars=[%v0]]
  Command 2: "expr {\"cmd.$x\"..."
    (12) push1 1        # "cmd."
    (14) loadScalar1 %v0        # var "x"
    (16) strcat 2
    (18) tryCvtToNumeric
    (19) lmap_collect
    (20) foreach_step
    (21) foreach_end
    (22) done

% tcl::unsupported::disassemble lambda {{} {
    lmap x {a b c} {return -level 0 cmd.$x}
}}
ByteCode 0x1ee2cfb01e0, refCt 1, epoch 19, interp 0x1ee2b47a820 (epoch 19)
  Source "lmap x {a b c} {return -level 0 cmd.$x}"
  Cmds 2, src 39, inst 22, litObjs 2, aux 1, stkDepth 6, code/src 0.00
  Proc 0x1ee2cfc68b0, refCt 1, args 0, compiled locals 1
      slot 0, scalar, "x"
  Exception ranges 1, depth 1:
      0: level 0, loop, pc 12-17, continue 19, break 20
  Commands 2:
      1: pc 0-20, src 0-38        2: pc 12-17, src 16-37
  Command 1: "lmap x {a b c} {return -level 0 cmd.$x}"
    (0) list 0
    (5) push1 0         # "a b c"
    (7) foreach_start 0
                [jumpOffset=-7, vars=[%v0]]
  Command 2: "return -level 0 cmd.$x..."
    (12) push1 1        # "cmd."
    (14) loadScalar1 %v0        # var "x"
    (16) strcat 2
    (18) lmap_collect
    (19) foreach_step
    (20) foreach_end
    (21) done


As you can see, the bytecode with string cat and return -level 0 is the same, and with expr {"..."} there's an extra opcode (and hence a jump offset is different to accommodate it).

Absolutely everything to do with using the zero level for things like return, uplevel and upvar tends to be a bit surprising. The suspicion is that some of them are in there because it was easier than preventing them...

i see the same output with puts [lmap x $your_list {list [lrange cmd.$x 0 end]}]
puts [lmap x {a b c} {return -level 0 cmd.$x}] what i am missing here?

Put both your and Donals lmap version into a procedure e.g. proc d {} {lmap x {a b c} {string cat cmd.$x}} and call tcl::unsupported::disassemble proc d and you will see that your version has lots more steps.

You could have also used expr "cmd.$x" in the body. Short, but not quite as efficient; an extra step to try to convert the result to a number is done (the expr compiler isn't smart enough to omit that opcode here).

I tried that before, but get invalid bareword "cmd"

Whoops, that should have been expr {"cmd.$x"}. It's a faintly ridiculous character sequence...

I am not sure why you refrain from using string trim , anyways you can use lrange
 set your_list {a b c}
 puts [lmap x $your_list {list [lrange cmd.$x 0 end]}]


because [string trim] and [lrange] are useless in my case

when you say useless , you have a problem with return type ? what is it ?

I cannot follow you. By "useless" I mean they don't add/modify the result ... even your example with lrange does not modify the result - so why shall one use lrange?

i see the same output with
puts [lmap x $your_list {list [lrange cmd.$x 0 end]}]
puts [lmap x {a b c} {return -level 0 cmd.$x}]
what i am missing here?
